# Celery with Django - AttributeError: 'AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, django, celery

I wrote a celery task that sets some values in my database when I click on a button on my web page. Everything is fine. Now I want to write a more complex task (disambiguation_task) that returns a string to my Django view (1.6.5). The code is:

```
task_id = disambiguation_task.apply_async([json.dumps(json_request)])
async_result = AsyncResult(id=task_id,app=disambiguation_task)
```

As soon as I try to get the result (async_result.get()), it generates an error:

```
AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

with the following traceback:

```
File "/home/patrick/django/entite-tracker-master/entitetracker/docentites/views.py" in get
  466.             result = async_result.get()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/result.py" in get
  169.             no_ack=no_ack,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py" in wait_for
  155.                                     on_interval=on_interval)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py" in consume
  225.             binding = self._create_binding(task_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py" in _create_binding
  99.         name = self.rkey(task_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py" in rkey
  111.         return task_id.replace('-', '')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /docentites/nodoc_desamb/news20150305NY501131/
Exception Value: 'AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Same error if I try to print async_result.state.
Can someone help me with this error?
Regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disambiguation_task.apply_async([json.dumps(json_request)])` returns AsyncResult object, not a task id. So simply:

```
task_result = disambiguation_task.apply_async([json.dumps(json_request)])

# if you need to use the task_id somewhere else
async_result = AsyncResult(id=task_result.id, app=disambiguation_task)
```